# webgl simple image effect

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create image filters using WebGL. i have found this library [WebGLImageFilter](https://github.com/phoboslab/WebGLImageFilter).The filter effect I am trying to get is `Rise Effect`
 from [CSSGram](https://una.im/CSSgram/). Here is the [source code](https://github.com/una/CSSgram/blob/master/source/css/rise.css) for that filter.
it basically does this:

- apply `brightness(1.05)`
- apply `sepia(0.2)`
- apply `contrast(0.9)`
- apply `saturate(0.9)`

In the give order, so i replicate this using the library i mentioned.

```js
const image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg";

image.onload = function() {
  try {
    var filter = new WebGLImageFilter();
  }
  catch( err ) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  filter.addFilter('brightness',1.05);
  filter.addFilter('sepia',0.2);
  filter.addFilter('contrast',0.9);
  filter.addFilter('saturation',0.9);
  
  var filteredImage = filter.apply(image);
  document.body.appendChild(filteredImage);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/phoboslab/WebGLImageFilter/e0eee0cd/webgl-image-filter.js"></script>
```

But this gives a very different image effect than the mentioned one.so I tried to apply each effect individually and each of them works perfectly but when I combine them I get a different effect than the one I am trying to achieve. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you're using doesn't take the same values as input.

For example CSS saturation takes a value 0 to 1 for how saturated. In other words 0 = no saturation, 1 = full saturation where as the library you linked to takes a positive or negative value for how much to *change* the saturation. In other words 0 = don't change the saturation. 1 = apply 1 amount of a saturation (amount being however much the library uses by default) and -1 remove one unit of saturation

Also AFAIK the sepia filter doesn't take an input. No matter what value you pass in for sepia it just makes the picture the same amount of sepia.

```js
const image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg";

image.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i += 0.25) {
    var filter = new WebGLImageFilter();
    filter.addFilter('sepia', i);
    var filteredImage = filter.apply(image);
    document.body.appendChild(filteredImage);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas { width: 100px; margin: 5px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/phoboslab/WebGLImageFilter/e0eee0cd/webgl-image-filter.js"></script>
```

Looking inside the library most of the filters are based on a 5x4 color matrix where the identity (the matrix that leaves the colors as they are) is

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0
```

For sepia it's just hard coded to

```
0.393, 0.7689999, 0.18899999, 0, 0,
0.349, 0.6859999, 0.16799999, 0, 0,
0.272, 0.5339999, 0.13099999, 0, 0,
0,0,0,1,0
```

The shader being used looks like this

```
precision highp float;  
varying vec2 vUv;  
uniform sampler2D texture;  
uniform float m[20];  

void main(void) {  
  vec4 c = texture2D(texture, vUv);  
  gl_FragColor.r = m[0] * c.r + m[1] * c.g + m[2] * c.b + m[3] * c.a + m[4];  
  gl_FragColor.g = m[5] * c.r + m[6] * c.g + m[7] * c.b + m[8] * c.a + m[9];  
  gl_FragColor.b = m[10] * c.r + m[11] * c.g + m[12] * c.b + m[13] * c.a + m[14];  
  gl_FragColor.a = m[15] * c.r + m[16] * c.g + m[17] * c.b + m[18] * c.a + m[19];  
}
```

Which if I understand correctly, reading cross the rows for sepia, means

```
new red = 39% red, 77% green, 19% blue
new green = 35% red, 69% green, 17% blue
new blue = 27% red, 53% green, 13% blue
new alpha = alpha
```

So to actually be able to set the amount you need have it be the identity matrix when amount = 0 and the sepia matrix when amount = 1. Fortunately it looks like there's a `colorMatrix` filter where you can pass in your own matrix. Let's try it

```js
const identity = [
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
];

const sepia = [
 0.393, 0.7689999, 0.18899999, 0, 0,
 0.349, 0.6859999, 0.16799999, 0, 0,
 0.272, 0.5339999, 0.13099999, 0, 0,
 0,0,0,1,0,
];

const image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg";

image.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i += 0.25) {
    var filter = new WebGLImageFilter();
    filter.addFilter('colorMatrix', mix(identity, sepia, i));
    var filteredImage = filter.apply(image);
    document.body.appendChild(filteredImage);
  }
}

function mix(m1, m2, amount) {
  return m1.map((a, ndx) => {
    const b = m2[ndx];
    return a + (b - a) * amount;
  });
}
```

```css
canvas { width: 100px; margin: 5px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/phoboslab/WebGLImageFilter/e0eee0cd/webgl-image-filter.js"></script>
```

Which seems to work?

```js
const identity = [
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
];

const sepia = [
 0.393, 0.7689999, 0.18899999, 0, 0,
 0.349, 0.6859999, 0.16799999, 0, 0,
 0.272, 0.5339999, 0.13099999, 0, 0,
 0,0,0,1,0,
];

const image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/una/CSSgram/6f21810a/site/img/atx.jpg";

image.onload = function() {
  try {
    var filter = new WebGLImageFilter();
  }
  catch( err ) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  filter.addFilter('brightness',-0.05); // 1.05);
  // filter.addFilter('sepia',0.2);
  filter.addFilter('colorMatrix', mix(identity, sepia, 0.2));
  filter.addFilter('contrast', -0.1); // 0.9);
  filter.addFilter('saturation', -0.1); //0.9);
  
  var filteredImage = filter.apply(image);
  document.body.appendChild(image);
  document.body.appendChild(filteredImage);
}

function mix(m1, m2, amount) {
  return m1.map((a, ndx) => {
    const b = m2[ndx];
    return a + (b - a) * amount;
  });
}
```

```css
img, canvas { 
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/phoboslab/WebGLImageFilter/e0eee0cd/webgl-image-filter.js"></script>
```

Comment: there should be some way right? It&#39;s a very small library of one js file , I should be able to make changes as required.but can you please give me some pointers on where to start if I need to achieve those effects

Comment: thankyou so much .let me try this out by making a change in this library

Comment: Well for one example if saturation in CSS is 0.3 (30% saturated) then in this one you might try passing in -0.7 (as in remove 70% of the saturation). For sepia though you need to change it to mix. Looking at the code it's using a 5x5 color matrix for most things where 1s going down the diagonal of the matrix = don't change the image so for sepia you need to change it so when amount = 0 the matrix is 1s down the diagonal of the matrix and when it's 1 the matrix is what it is now.  Either that or you could change the entire library to match CSS so that amount = absolute amount instead of change

Comment: also i wanted to thank you for the excellent tutorial that you have written about WebGL fundamentals because those are the one which i referred to learn basics of webgl & understand how things work. i just now realised you are greggman. :D

Comment: i understand now how to go about it, thanks for the detailed analyis of the problem but i am little confused about how the `mix()` function works?can you please explain it a little

Comment: specially what this equation `a + (b - a) * amount` does?

Comment: it does a linear interpolation between `a` and `b` based on `amount`. When `amount` = 0 it's `a`. When `amount` = 1 it's `b`. When `amount` = 0.3 it's 30% `b` and 70% `a`.   Look at it this way.  `b - a` is the difference between `a` and `b`. It's what you need to add to `a` to get `b`.  So if you multiply that by 0 you get `a + (deltaToB * 0)` which is `a`.  If you multiply that by 1 you get `a + (deltaToB * 1)` which is `b`.